# Generate classification schema in ArcGIS Pro using labeled raster - fail

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, classification, landsat-8

Trying to do supervised classification of L1TP Landsat 8 OLI bands using USDA [Crop Data Layer](https://www.nass.usda.gov/Research_and_Science/Cropland/SARS1a.php) .tif file through ArcGIS Pro. The Crop Data Layer file has one band, with labels like "Corn", "Cotton", "Rice." Doing image classification through ArcGIS pro requires a [classification schema](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/image-analyst/overview-of-image-classification.htm), with the default being National Land Cover Database. Classification Wizard offers "Generate Classification Schema from Classified Raster," but inputting the Crop Data Layer .tif file into this generates the following error: "Failed to generate classification schema from classified raster." No other explanations attached.

[image: error message from generation]

Not sure if there is something inherently off about the CDL file format/way the info is organized? All search results about generating classification schema lead to drawing polygons--should I export the CDL raster as a polygon?

Below is the attribute table for Crop Data Layer:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [generating training sample schema in Arcpro [sic]](https://community.esri.com/thread/234094-generating-training-sample-schema-in-arcpro):

Apparently the solution was to change the field names:

- classname
- classvalue